# Change ContentControl Content from Content ViewModel programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:StartPageViewModel}">
        <local1:StartPage/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:SecondPageViewModel}">
        <local1:SecondPage/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Label Content="[res][per]" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CommandStartView}">
            First
        </Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding CommandSecondView}">
            Second
        </Button>            
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Pages" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private object selectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public ICommand CommandStartView { get; set; }
    public ICommand CommandSecondView { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

        CommandStartView = new RelayCommand(openStartView);
        CommandSecondView = new RelayCommand(openSecondView);

    }

    private void openStartView(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new StartPageViewModel();
    }

    private void openSecondView(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new SecondPageViewModel();
    }

}
```

**StartPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="First Page" />
    <Button Content="Second" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CommandSecondView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    <Button Content="Do Something" Command="{Binding CommandDoBeforeSecondView}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**StartPageViewModel.cs**

```
class StartPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand CommandDoBeforeSecondView { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {

        CommandDoBeforeSecondView = new RelayCommand(openSecondView);
    }

    private void openSecondView(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DO SOME CODE");

        //Then change Content programmatically

    }
 }
```

**Question:**
How can I change the Content from the MainWindow ContentControl using the second button in the StartPage? I want to execute some code and then change the content.

In relation of the first comment I think I have to add a reference the MainWindowViewModel in my StartPageViewModel, how i make this?

**EDIT**

My working Solution:

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private void openStartView(object obj)
{
    SelectedViewModel = new StartPageViewModel(this);
}
```

StartPageViewModel.cs

```
class StartPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainWindowViewModel mainWindow;
    public ICommand CommandDoBeforeSecondView { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel(MainWindowViewModel _mainWindow)
    {
        mainWindow = _mainWindow;
        CommandDoBeforeSecondView = new RelayCommand(openSecondView);
    }

    private void openSecondView(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DO SOME CODE");
        mainWindow.SelectedViewModel = new SecondPageViewModel();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, making it also too broad. Based on the tiny bit of code you shared, you do seem to already have a template for your view model. And you understand that setting the `SelectedViewModel` to a different value will change the view model object used. So, _what is your question_? Just set that property to whatever you want. Just give your `StartPageViewModel` a reference to the `MainViewModel` object, or subscribe the `MainViewModel` object to a suitable event on the `StartPageViewModel`, where you can the via that reference or event be able to change the property value.

Comment: The above still is not a [mcve]. You have code that doesn't need to be there (`BoolToVisConverter` resource), and you are missing the second page code (never mind the `RelayCommand`, which is not built-in). Based on what you posted, you should just pass `this` when creating `StartPageViewModel` in the `MainWindowViewModel`, then the `StartPageViewModel` will have the reference (you'll have to add the parameter to the constructor of course). An alternative, if you want to be able to declare everything in XAML, is to just add a property that can be set to the right value.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I shortened the code to the relevant code, but forgot to delete the `BoolToVisConverter`. The SecondPage Code just has a lable with "Second Page".

Comment: Have you tried either of my suggestions? They represent the two most common ways to pass a value from one class to another.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried and it works, I add the solution to the Post.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, you should post that solution as an actual answer, **not** as an edit in your original question. Then mark that answer as "accepted", so that others know your question no longer needs an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working Solution:

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private void openStartView(object obj)
{
    SelectedViewModel = new StartPageViewModel(this);
}
```

StartPageViewModel.cs

```
class StartPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainWindowViewModel mainWindow;
    public ICommand CommandDoBeforeSecondView { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel(MainWindowViewModel _mainWindow)
    {
        mainWindow = _mainWindow;
        CommandDoBeforeSecondView = new RelayCommand(openSecondView);
    }

    private void openSecondView(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DO SOME CODE");
        mainWindow.SelectedViewModel = new SecondPageViewModel();

    }
}
```

Thx to Peter Duniho he answered it the comments above:

> you should just pass this when creating StartPageViewModel in the MainWindowViewModel, then the StartPageViewModel will have the reference (you'll have to add the parameter to the constructor of course)